# Not all exceptions are mapping to resolveException in SimpleMappingExceptionResolver

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm overriding `resolveException` in `SimpleMappingExceptionResolver` in order to send an email with the stacktrace which works for 500 errors but a 400 error does not arrive at this method. (There is no stacktrace to send but I'd still like to send an email and show a nice error page.)

Is there a way to do this or should i just configure my web.xml to handle 400 (and similar)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll find this answer helpful:

[Spring SimpleMappingExceptionResolver not going to default view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967016/spring-simplemappingexceptionresolver-not-going-to-default-view)

TL;DR Spring ExceptionResolvers don't handle all exceptions, just those thrown by Controllers.  A "400 - Bad Request" can be thrown when Spring can't convert your submission data for a mapped controller, and the exception it throws would never be seen by your ExceptionHandler.

Your web.xml solution should work nicely.