# SimpleMappingExceptionResolver does not seem to work

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

We are having some problems with the SimpleMappingExceptionResolver. However the custom error page is never triggered. What is wrong with this configuration? Or are we missing something that we also should have configured in order to make it work? I tried with other exceptions too.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">      
    <property name="exceptionMappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="javax.ejb.TransactionRolledbackLocalException">transaction-rollback</prop>                
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="defaultStatusCode" value="500"/>
    <property name="defaultErrorView" value="internal-error"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/q/11792231/420613

Comment: But we don't want to add it in the controllers. We want to keep that detail in the definition.