# Spring + Tiles (+Portal) base error page

Tags: java, spring, tiles, portal

I'm trying to do something which seems like it should be pretty straightforward to me, but doesn't seem to be working...  I have a page composed of tiles and at the moment there is an exception in the render phase of one of the jsps, causing my error page to be shown - but this is only shown *in the tile in which it occurs*.  What I would really like is the whole page to show the error, not just one of the tiles, surely this is possible?

The error page shown is defined in the web.xml and contains `<%@ page isErrorPage="true" %>` and I have also tried adding `<%@ page errorPage="/errorPage.jsp" %>` to my baselayout.jsp but this doesn't seem to be recognised - I can put in any value and it doesn't give an error or anything.  Does tiles not have an option to propagate the exception up to the parent jsp rather than just displaying the error in each tile?

SimpleMappingExceptionResolver for example won't work, as the exception is in the render phase. I have tried implementing a HandlerInterceptor as recommended in [Spring SimpleMappingExceptionResolver not going to default view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967016/spring-simplemappingexceptionresolver-not-going-to-default-view) however in the afterResourceCompletion() method the exception parameter is null, which is where I thought my exception would be.

I have also had a look at http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=1071592 which seems to indicate that there's an issue with the older version of Struts - does Spring share this issue?

Hopefully I'm missing something very simple here, any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like it's an issue with the way JSP handles exceptions, outlined at http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM22919

For me, fixpack 15 for version 7 of WebSphere Portal adds a new property com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.dispatcherRethrowSError which I set to true, that passes the exception up to the calling class(es).

All properties are outlined at http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Finfo%2Fexp%2Fae%2Frweb_custom_props.html